# How can I order a job in Control-M using a message queue?

Tags: message, message-queue, control-m

I am trying to find a way to order a Control-M job via a message from an external application.  We are using Control-M v8.  We are able to send messages to the queue, but we have been unsuccessful in receiving messages that perform some sort of action in Control-m.

Answer (score 0):

Erick, look at the documentation for the Control-M Business Process Integration Suite Manual.  This suite provides the capability that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

We have application back-end in UNix and, we use Control-M in-built utilities to call jobs from unix. The jobs should be created in desktop, and should have been uploaded to control M database without any specific schedule. A utility called 'ctmorder' can be used to call these jobs as and when required.